# Can't connect to wifi via wpa_supplicant

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I've searched in different forums how to connect to a wpa network with the terminal but none of the seems to work

In the network managager file "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/elhackerderivendel" I have:

```
[connection]
id=elhackerderivendel
uuid=2ec1e3d4-31ea-4d08-9aa4-6afc82324186
type=802-11-wireless
timestamp=1322936420

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=elhackerderivendel
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=ac:81:12:bb:28:e
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA #this is not my real password as you can expect

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
method=auto
```

And on the other hand iwconfig tells me

```
- Device: wlan0  [elhackerderivendel] ------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            brcmsmac
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        AC:81:12:BB:28:0E

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           28 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes
```

And sudo wpa_cli scan_results

```
Selected interface 'wlan0'
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
00:0e:2e:c2:11:00   2462    188 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP-preauth][ESS]    elhackerderivendel
00:0b:3b:cc:95:e4   2427    177 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   elhackerderivendel
```

Any idea of what to write in the wpa_supplicant.conf?

Answer (score 2):

```
man wpa_supplicant.conf
```

would have given you the answer. Anyway, here's it:

```
 ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wheel
      #
      # home network; allow all valid ciphers
      network={
           ssid="home"
           scan_ssid=1
           key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
           psk="very secret passphrase"
      }
      #
```